# Loading objects in Model, what is wrong?

Tags: cakephp

I have an object type called Blurb in my cake app, I tried to print them out but it gave an error:

Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: /....../app/Model/Blurb.php
Line: 19

What's wrong with the code below?

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Blurb extends AppModel {

    public $name = 'Blurb';

    public function afterSave($created, $options = array()){
        $allBlurbs = $this->Blurb->find('all');
        var_dump($allBlurbs);
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyword $this refers to instance of class Blurb, so $this is Blurb.

`$this->Blurb->find('all')` means this - from actual object take method (or parameter) called Blurb an from him evolve method 'find' with parameter all.

If you have method find in your Blurb class, you need this:

```
$this->find('all');
```